# Make a object accessible by only its library, and not by any other routine in the program

Tags: c++, c, object

Lets say I have two (or more) c functions `func1()` and `func2()` both requiring a buffer variable `int buff`. If both functions are kept in separate files, *func1.c* and *func2.c*, How do I make it so that `buff` is accessible to only `func1()` and `func2()` and not to the calling routine(or any other routine).
Here is an example setup:

file *func1.c*:

```c
/*func1.c*/
static int buff;

int *func1(int x)
{
    buff = x;
    return &buff;
}
```

file *func2.c*:

```c
/*func2.c*/
static int buff;

int *func2(int x)
{
    buff = x;
    return &buff;
}
```

header *header.h*:

```c
/*header for func1.c and func2.c*/
//multiple inclusion guard not present.
int *func1(int);
int *func2(int);
```

file *main.c*:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include"header.h"

int main()
{
    int *ptr;

    ptr = func1(1);
    printf("&buff = %p , buff = %d\n", ptr, *ptr);
    ptr = func2(2);
    printf("&buff = %p , buff = %d\n", ptr, *ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

As expected, the output shows different memory locations for buff.

```
&buff = 0x55b8fd3f0034 , buff = 1
&buff = 0x55b8fd3f0038 , buff = 2
```

But I need only one copy buff, not more.
I could of course, put both functions in the same file, and define `buff` as **static int** but then I would lose the ability to compile the functions separately.
If I put `int buff` in a separate *buff.c* and declare it **extern** in *func1.c* and *func2.c*, but then it would be easily accessible by the calling routine(main in this case).

---

Basically, I need to create a library of functions that work on the same external object, that is accessible only to them. The calling routine may not need all the functions, so I do not want to put them in a single file and create unused code. But there must be only one copy of the object.

Please help on how I could do the same, if it is achievable.

Comment: You have to put all functions needing `buff` as a "private" variable in the same file.

Comment: "... so I do not want to put them in a single file and create unused code." Unless you have a huge collection of functions I wouldn't worry.

Comment: You suggested you're building a library.  I'm pretty sure there are decent ways to manipulate a library's symbol table after the fact, to adjust things like the visibility of symbols.  So you could (a) use an ordinary global variable, (b) build your library, (c) tweak the library to make the global variable non-global, and (d) rest secure that your library's clients can't cheat and peek t it.

Comment: @SteveSummit,  I did the workarounds and tweaks, basically I curious  to too see how much size(meaning file size) of the final executable could be reduced by discarding the "unused code", of the unused function definitions.

Comment: @SiddharthBhat What kind of library are you building? `.a`, `.so`, `.lib`, `.dll`, or something else?

Comment: For "conventional" libraries (`.a`, `.lib`), and static linking, I would expect that splitting up your source files, so that unneeded functions are not copied into the final executable, would help make the final executable smaller.  But for dynamically-linked libraries (`.so`, `.dll`), as I understand it, everything always ends up in the loaded library anyway, but none of it ends up in an executable that uses the library, so I wouldn't expect it to make a difference.

Comment: @SteveSummit, A static library, I have somewhat a vague idea of what dynamic libraries are, but ain't got a excuse to use them yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One typical approach to this problem is to give the global variable a name that begins with `_`.

That is, in func1.c you might write

```
int _mylib_buff;
```

And then in func2.c, of course, you'd have

```
extern int _mylib_buff;
```

Now, of course, in this case, `_mylib_buff` is technically an ordinary global variable.  It's not truly "private" at all.  But global variables beginning with `_` are private "by convention", and I'd say this works okay in practice.  But, obviously, there's nothing preventing some other source file from cheating and peeking at the nominally-private variable, and there's no way in Standard C to prevent one from doing so.

The other complication is that some identifiers beginning with `_` are reserved to the implementation, and you're not supposed to use them in your own code.  (That is, components of the implementation -- like your C compiler and C library -- have semi-global variables they're trying to hide from you, and they're typically using a leading `_` to achieve this, also.)  I'm pretty sure the rules say it's okay for you to define a global variable beginning with a leading underscore followed by a lower-case letter, but the rules are somewhat complicated, and I can never remember all the nuances.  See questions  [1.9](http://c-faq.com/decl/semiglobal.html) and [1.29](http://c-faq.com/decl/namespace.html) in the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: Putting a `_` in front of the variable name solves nothing. The variable is still available to any compilation unit.

Comment: @4386427 Did you read my answer where I explained that?

Answer (score 3):

The C standard does not provide a way to do this. It is usually done using features of compilers and linkers beyond the C standard. Here is an example using Apple’s developer tools on macOS. For options suitable to your environment, you should specify the build tools and versions you are using, such as whether you are using Apple tools, GNU tools, Microsoft tools, or something else.

With this in `a.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x = 123;

void a(void)
{
    printf("In a.c, x is %d.\n", x);
}
```

and this in `b.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int x;

void b(void)
{
    printf("In b.c, x is %d.\n", x);
}
```

we compile the source files to object modules:

```
clang -c a.c b.c
```

and then link them to a new object module `r.o` while requesting that the symbol `x` (`_x` in the linker view) not be exported:

```
ld -r -o r.o -unexported_symbol _x a.o b.o
```

Then, if we have another source file `c.c` that attempts to use `x`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int x;

extern void a(void);
extern void b(void);

int main(void)
{
    a();
    b();
    printf("In c.c, x is %d.\n", x);
}
```

attempting to build an executable with it using `clang -o c c.c r.o`  yields:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_x", referenced from:
      _main in c-139a35.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

However, if we remove the two lines in `c.c` that refer to `x`, the build succeeds, and the program prints:

```
In a.c, x is 123.
In b.c, x is 123.
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: It's not possible.

C has no way of saying "this variable may be used by source file x, y, z and not by any other sources files".

So if you want `buff` to be "private" to a number of functions, you'll have to put those functions in the same source file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the non-static variable in one of the files for example:

```
int buff;

int *func1(int x)
{
    buff = x;
    return &buff;
}
```

in the header file declare it as `extern`:

```
/*header for func1.c and func2.c*/
//multiple inclusion guard not present.

extern int buff;

int *func1(int);
int *func2(int);
```

Include it in all other files:

```
/*func2.c*/
#include "header.h"

int *func1(int x)
{
    buff = x;
    return &buff;
}
```

If you do not want variable to be visible you need to create function which will get and set the "hidden" variable.

```
typedef enum
{
    GET,
    SET,
    REF,
}OP_t;


#define CREATE(type, name) type getset##name(OP_t oper, type val, type **ref) \
{\
    static type buff;\
    switch(oper)\
    {\
        case GET:\
            return buff;\
        case SET:\
            buff = val;\
            break;\
        case REF:\
            if(ref) *ref = &buff;\
            break;\
    }\
    return 0;\
}\

#define HEAD(type, name) type getset##name(OP_t oper, type val, type **ref)
#define GETVAL(name) getset##name(GET, 0, NULL)
#define SETVAL(name,val) getset##name(SET, val, NULL)
#define GETREF(name,ref) getset##name(REF, 0, ref)
```

Comment: OP want `buff` to be inaccesible to all other functions than `func1` and `func2` so this doesn't solve OPs problem. With this approach every source file that includes the header may access the buffer.